# Does the net induced emf decrease in this case?

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-current, electromagnetic-induction, lenz-law

In a video from the YouTube channel veritasium about [Misconceptions of electricity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bHIhgxav9LY&t)

It is said that energy is mostly of the electric fields produced by the surface charges and battery , which make them move in the circuit hence providing energy.

If we consider the simple case of two co-axial solenoids that are on top of each other , they are in an appreciable distance such that their magnetic field is experienced by the other if one passes current in one of the solenoids.

Then the electric fields due to the surface charges also produce a current which is in the same direction as the current flowing in the first coil so the net induced EMF reduces in the coil that is getting induced current due to change in magnetic field due to change in current!

Why do we not account for this and just give the formula for the induced current to be

$I_{induced} = \frac{E_{induced}}{R}$ and $I_{induced}= \frac{-L\dfrac{di}{dt}}{R}$

Where the $I_{induced}$ must be reduced by the opposite flow of current due to this effect ?

Edit:
An image to see what is happening , excuse me for the poor diagram but the magnetic flux changes in such a direction the induced current from the bigger solenoid is in the opposite direction of the current due to surface charges of bigger solenoid , so the net induced current is low than the actual value ?
[image]

Comment: There seems to be a crucial statement with a lot of inducing happening; can you please get a picture of that so that we have a better understanding of what it is you are actually trying to tell us to consider?

Comment: Is your power source DC or AC when you are talking about this? If its DC, then there is no such problem.

Comment: there is change in current such that there is a change in magnetic flux , so It would be AC but can you tell how DC would have no issues ?